# Create new page locations FACEBOOK API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a new location for an existing page using an APP with Standard Access, but It's show me an error "Only white-listed APP can create new pages using this endpoint /{page_id}/locations".

- Facebook SDK PHP
- Facebook Graph API v2.9
- My code:

  ```
  $fb = new Facebook(['app_id' => app_idp,'app_secret' => app_secret,]);
  $fb->setDefaultAccessToken(master_page_access_token);
  $new_location['hours'] = array("mon_1_open"=> "10:00",
          "mon_1_close"=>"19:00",
          "tue_1_open"=> "10:00",
          "tue_1_close"=> "19:00",
          "wed_1_open"=>"10:00",
          "wed_1_close"=> "19:00",
          "thu_1_open"=> "10:00",
          "thu_1_close"=> "19:00",
          "fri_1_open"=> "10:00",
          "fri_1_close"=> "19:00",
          "sat_1_open"=>"10:00",
          "sat_1_close"=>"19:00"
  );
  $location =  array(
          'hours'=>$new_location['hours'],
          'location'=> array(
          'street'=>$full_address,
          'latitude' => $latitude,
          'longitude'=> $longitude,
          'city_id'=> $city_id,
          'zip'=> $zip),
          'phone' => $phone ,
          'place_topics'=>array('210979565595898',
                  '199512783398620',
                  '108472109230615'),
          'price_range' => '$$',
          'store_location_descriptor' => $store_location_descriptor,
          'store_name'=> $store_name,
          'store_number'=> $store_id,
  );
  try {
          $new_pages =  $fb->post('/{page_id}/locations',$location,master_page_access_token); 
  } 
  catch (Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $exc) {
          echo $exc->getMessage();
  }
  ```
- Error
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO7LZ.png)